# DDR4 routing / spacing guidelines

Tags: memory, timing, routing

Where can I find the source of routing guidelines for DDR4.  I'm talking about things like DQ to DQS timing, maximum length difference in ps for address and command and maybe maximum parallel run lengths.

In my search, I see various articles talking about what you should do but no definitive source.  I looked in the DDR4 JEDEC spec but didn't see much mention of PCB routing.

Comment: It isn't in your chips datasheet?

Answer (score 2):

This [Altera app note](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/external-memory/emi_plan_board_ddr2.pdf) seems to have it all.

You can also download [sample design files](http://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/focus/memory-module-designs-dimms/DDR4/all) from JEDEC, and get some idea about routing topologies etc.